# Removing outline from a pseudo element that is focused

Tags: css, pseudo-element, pseudo-class

I'm trying to create a logging script, with anchors a link to specific lines.  There's a header, which pushes everything down; now, these links of course, pull the content into view behind the header, and so I needed a way to bring them into focus past the header.

Pseudo elements to the rescue!  At least, partly; the problem which came to light is that they each have a focus outline, for the links when clicked.  Try as I might, I've been unable to get rid of this outline.  Now, normally, an outline like this wouldn't really be a problem; it is here, however, given that the lines in the log come right after another, ala:

[image: Annoying outline is annoying]

As to what I've tried?  Well, I've attempted to select the pseudo element's focus pseudo class, unsuccessfully:

The html, for reproduction of the problem;

```html
<a id="1" href="#1">[123456]</a><br />
<a id="2" href="#2">[123456]</a><br />
<a id="3" href="#3">[123456]</a><br />
<a id="4" href="#4">[123456]</a><br />
<a id="5" href="#5">[123456]</a><br />
<a id="6" href="#6">[123456]</a><br />
<a id="7" href="#7">[123456]</a><br />
<a id="8" href="#8">[123456]</a><br />
<a id="9" href="#9">[123456]</a><br />
<a id="10" href="#10">[123456]</a><br />
<a id="11" href="#11">[123456]</a><br />
```

The css, for the attempt at solving the problem(as well as reproduction)

```css
a::before {
    display: block;
    content: " ";  
    margin-top: -100px;
    height: 100px;
    visibility: hidden;
}

a:focus::before { outline: none; }
a:active::before { outline: none; }
```

And finally, the jsfiddle, for a live example of the problem; to see the annoying outline, just click any link: [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Daedalus/061coacy/)

TL;DR: I'm having difficulty removing a pseudo element's focus outline.

Comment: How about `a{outline: none;}`? http://jsfiddle.net/imtheman/061coacy/1/

Comment: @imtheman God, I am such an idiot.  I should have attempted that, then I wouldn't have wasted people's time; if you could put that as an answer, I'd accept it.  I thought the problem was with the pseudo elements.

Comment: For those that are wondering, since removing the outline from a link is considered bad practice, I slipped a span in the link and applied the outline to that instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First rule of CSS, start simple, then work your way up. Pseudo elements are usually more of a last resort, but they can be very useful. As for this question the simplest way does indeed work.

```
a {
    outline: none;
}
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/imtheman/061coacy/3/)

**Update:**

Here is a simplified version of your code: http://jsfiddle.net/imtheman/061coacy/4/